# Sass injecting commas for mixins with multiple properties

Tags: sass, gruntjs

My version of Sass doesn't seem to be compiling correctly when using mixins with multiple values. When I use something like the below code:

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset: false) {
  @if $inset {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset $top $left $blur $color;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset $top $left $blur $color;
    box-shadow:inset $top $left $blur $color;
  } @else {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color;
    -moz-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color;
    box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color;
  }
}

.drop-shadow{
    @include box-shadow(10px, 5px, 5px, #383838);
}
```

I get the result:

```
.drop-shadow {
  box-shadow: 10px, 5px, 5px, #383838;
}
```

Chrome then proceeds to refuse to accept the property as valid because of the commas between the property values.

Has anyone seen anything like this or know how to fix it I can't find any other articles of anyone talking about this kind of issue.

I am using:

- Compass 0.12.6 (Alnilam)
- grunt-cli v0.1.13
- grunt v0.4.5

I tried to recreate the issue on codePen but it seems to work fine. http://codepen.io/jpeak/pen/AbrJa

Comment: Are you sure you aren't importing either Compass in its entirety or the [box-shadow mixins](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_shadow/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer it seems for some reason compass is treating the commas after each property as apart of the property and transposing them.

So

```
@include box-shadow(10px, 5px, 5px, #383838);
```

=

```
box-shadow: 10px, 5px, 5px, #383838;
```

and

```
@include box-shadow(10px 5px 5px #383838);
```

=

```
box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #383838;
```

not sure if anyone can explain why this is happening.